# Configurar ASP.NET MVC + IIS para devolver un archivo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

En una aplicación ASP.NET MVC (C#) tengo la necesidad de mostrar un archivo PDF en el browser pero además es necesario que puedan obtenerse dicho PDF.

Lo que tengo armado es un *Action* de la siguiente forma:

```
public ActionResult ExportarAPDF()
    {
        report.ExportToPdf(exportPath);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(exportPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        return new FileStreamResult(fs, "application/pdf");
    }
```

Esto, si lo ejecuto desde el navegador o incluso desde un *Postman* funciona correctamente, un sistema externo necesita obtenerse el PDF y me comenta que no puede, le arroja el mensaje: "Connection Reset".

Estuve investigando y podría faltarme alguna configuración en web.config o incluso en IIS pero no encontré nada claro respecto a esto así que acudo a ustedes para ver si me pueden orientar.

Espero haber sido claro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente he solucionado el problema.

No tuve que hacer ningún cambio en mi código, el sistema externo hizo algunos cambios (no puedo saber cuáles) y logró bajarse el PDF.

Así que el código original funciona.